# embed json into form when POST

Tags: python, json, flask

this is not ajax, but much simpler.

What I have is a form of bunch of fields and rendered into html. my web site's visitors will access that page and fill out the form and click 'submit' button.

I have some data gathered by javascript/jquery which is running on that web page. I want flask to receive that data in POST(as JSON), with other 'normal' form values.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hidden field in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="">
```

Then use jQuery's `submit()` method to intercept the form as it's being submitted and add your json there.